# Spanx class not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Twitter Bootstrap. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Scafffolding: Fixed</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
.span12{
background: black;
color: white;
padding: 20px 0;
text-align: center;
}
.span6{
background: blue;
color: white;
padding: 20px 0;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">Span12</div>        
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">Span6</div>
        <div class="span6">Span6</div>
    </div>          
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected the output to consist of first row, followed by two columns in the second row. But the output consists of 3 rows. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using Bootstrap 2, which uses a conventional box model. By adding padding to your spans, you've effectively widened them, so they no longer fit in a single row and wrap.

Instead, add a child div to your `span*` elements and put margin on that.

Bootstrap 3 alleviates some of these issues by applying `box-sizing: border-box` across the board, which includes padding in width calculations.

Comment: Sorry, actually I use bootstrap 3.1.1.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think I should use Bootstrap for my web design? or I should hard code?

Comment: That type of discussion isn't appropriate in the comments here, and I don't know enough about your project anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap 2 spans, but you say you're using Bootstrap 3.1.

Instead of doing

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">Span6</div>
    <div class="span6">Span6</div>
</div>
```

which is the Bootstrap 2 way of creating columns, you should be doing something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">Span6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Span6</div>
</div>
```

The class names were changed because Bootstrap 3 uses a mobile-first approached, as opposed to Bootstrap 2. The code I showed you here will float the divs in 2 columns, and then when you are viewing them on a mobile screen, they'll collapse to one column. If you wanted them stay in 2 columns regardless of screen size, you would change col-sm-6 to col-xs-6.

Here's the documentation on the Bootstrap 3 scaffolding system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Comment: Very helpful!! for what kind of web site design, do you recommend the use of Bootstrap?

Comment: It's great for all kinds of sites. :) I mainly use it for rapid prototyping, or if I know a site will need to be responsive on a budget, then it makes things a lot quicker.

Comment: Do you think even fontend of like www.quora.com can be created with bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap is just a CSS framework, so really it can be used anywhere CSS can be used. Although it can be tricky to implement into an already complex site or web app, but like I said it's merely a CSS framework and is meant to be built upon. You could certainly build a site like Quora using Bootstrap as a starting point to style the frontend, but that's only a very small part of it. It really depends on what the requirements of your project are.